# Ansible playbook string search

Tags: regex, ansible

I have an Ansible play. It makes a URI call to a server and returns this string : "cloud\nuser-number 6a70a42c\nztp-status success\nconfig-template-name \"zero_zule\"\npseudo-confirm-commit "

I want to assign user-number to a variable in the play. I've tinkered with regex, but have difficulty in getting just the "6a70a42c" into the variable.

Any regex experts that could help me formulate the regex pattern would be much appreciated. Alternatively  , any one suggest a different approach that works? Need more than just a general answer (means a code example, please).

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
(?<=user-number\s)(\w+)
```

https://regexr.com/51np7